# What is the equivalent node command for "npm start" in this case?

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

This is a segment of package.json on my PC.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "http-server -p 8000",
}
```

When I run `npm start`, the http server starts with no problem.

When I run `node http-server -p 8000`, errors appear. Here are the errors;

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/owncode/http-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:680:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:628:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

What is the correct way to run the equivalent node command for `npm start`?

Answer (score 3):

`http-server` is a binary executable. You need to locate it. It is found inside the `node_modules` folder.

Assuming the location of `http-server` is as below, try the following;

```
node node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 8000
```

Comment: Do you mean `node_modules/.bin/http-server`? That's where installed bin scripts would usually get linked to. In addition, running `npm bin` will tell you the location of the bin scripts.

Answer (score 1):

install `http-server` as global package using following command.

```
npm install -g http-server
```

then you can run `http-server -p 8000` directly instead of *node http-server -p 8000*

Note: use `sudo npm install -g http-server` if your get permission errors.